# Circular variance

Tags: variance, standard-deviation, moments, circular-statistics

I'm attempting to replicate a particular analysis of circular data.

The author of this analysis writes

> I calculated . . . variance . . . for the observed recall errors, defining variance as the square of the circular SD ($\sigma ^2$) and using . . . SD . . . for circular data given by Fisher (1995), as follows:
>
> $\sigma=\sqrt{-2\log|\bar{m}_1|}$
>
> . . . where $\bar{m}_n$ is the $n$th uncentered trigonometric moment.

Fisher (1995) appears in fact to be the book *Statistical analysis of circular data* published by Fisher in 1993.

Several things about this confuse me:

1) Fisher does not define circular variance as the square of circular SD, as defined above.  He defines circular variance as $\nu = 1-\rho$, where $\rho$ is the *mean resultant length*, defined as follows:

\begin{align}
C &= \sum^n_{i=1}\cos\theta_i\\
S &= \sum^n_{i=1}\sin\theta_i\\
R^2&=C^2+S^2\\
\bar{R}&=R/n\\
\hat{\rho}&=\bar{R}
\end{align}
("The '$\hat{}$' denotes a sample estimate for the population quantity it surmounts.")

2) Fisher doesn't even define the circular SD the way the author I'm following does.  According to Fisher, $\sigma=\sqrt{-2\log\rho}$.  For this to be consistent with the author I'm following, we need $\rho=|\bar{m}_1|$.  However, Fisher defines $\bar{m}_1$ as $\bar{m}_1=\rho e^{i\mu}$, where $\mu$ is the *mean direction* (not necessarily zero, from what I can tell).

Can anyone bring some clarity to this situation?  What is the correct way to compute circular variance?

Comment: for fisher the first *centered* trigonometric moment equals $\hat{\rho}$.  so maybe the author meant centered?  but then why the absolute value?

Comment: Maybe the vertical bars should be double vertical bars, to represent a euclidean norm? The correct way uses $\sqrt{- 2 \log \bar{R}}$.

Comment: @KeesMulder the euclidean norm hypothesis doesn't make sense to me because (unless i'm mistaken) $\bar{m}_1$ is a scalar.

Comment: Trigonometric moments are defined as points (vectors) lying within the circle, or complex numbers. The direction is the mean direction, the vector length is the mean resultant length.

Comment: @KeesMulder are you saying that $\hat{\rho} = \bar{R} = ||\bar{m}_1||$?

Comment: Yes. The first equality, for sure. The second is kind of guessing what your author means, but also, yes. The double bars kind of imply that there is a Euclidean norm for a complex number $\bar{m}_1$, which I think is more commonly called the modulus of the complex number.